# JTable sort ascending empty cells on top

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable

How can I have empty cells in a JTable appear below cells with values when I click on the column header to sort in Ascending order. Right now, the empty cells appear above cells with numbers 1 and 2 in them.

```
TableRowSorter<TableModel> tableRowSorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(spreadsheetModel)
{
    Comparator<Object> comparator = new Comparator<Object>()  
    {  
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) 
        {  
            try
            {           
                Double d1 = Double.parseDouble(o1.toString());  
                Double d2 = Double.parseDouble(o2.toString());  
                return d1.compareTo(d2);  
            } 
            catch (NumberFormatException numberFormatException) 
            {  
                try 
                {  
                    Integer i1 = Integer.parseInt(o1.toString());  
                    Integer i2 = Integer.parseInt(o2.toString());  
                    return i1.compareTo(i2);  
                } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                {  
                    return o1.toString().compareTo(o2.toString());  
                }  
            }


        }  
    };

    public Comparator getComparator(int column)  
    {  
        return comparator;  
    };  
};                      

for(int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++)
    tableRowSorter.setComparator(i, tableRowSorter.getComparator(i));

tableRowSorter.setSortKeys(null);
table.setRowSorter(tableRowSorter);
table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Before doing you comparison you can check for nulls. Something like:

```
// Handle sorting of null values

if (o1 == null && o2 == null) return 0;

if (o1 == null) return 1;

if (o2 == null) return -1;
```

Comment: I tried adding this in my comparator before comparisons, but the empty cells still appear on top. The comparator does not see the nulls.

Comment: @stevetronix, post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) demonstrating the problem.